# How do you stop names from doubling - Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, backdrop

I have a membership database and a View of Local Leaders info, but it is showing each person twice in the View's list. I have tried to delete the contacts and input them back in they still show up double.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  It's not clear what you mean by "show up double".  Could you edit your question to include a screenshot so folks can help you better? Thanks!

Comment: If I type in a name and address it will show double in my Look up Leaders in the CRM. How do you clear it so there will be no double name

Comment: Hi Robin - I'm sorry, but the "Look up Leaders" is specific to your install, so I don't know what you're referring to.  A screenshot would be very helpful!

Comment: Where do I send the screenshot to.................to show what I am talking about in my CiviCRM database.

Comment: You can click "Edit" under your original question and add the screenshot to your question.

Comment: I did the screen shot and took me a minute figure out what to do. I have attach it to original question. Thanks for helping me Jon G. Megaphone. New at this!

Comment: Thank you so very much Laryn CEDC.org it work perfect. It was the "Other" phone that cause it. Glad I am on here.......................

Comment: No problem @Robin! Glad it worked. If you get a chance mark the answer as accepted (and you may want to edit the screenshot out again since it contains private information).

Answer (score 4):

If I had to guess, I'd say your "Look up Leaders" functionality is built with Views in Drupal or Backdrop, and it shows up double because there are two different "Other" phone numbers for these contacts. It's treating them as two different entries.

If that is the case and if it's possible to remove or relabel the second phone number location type in the contact records (ie. not have two "Other" phone numbers -- although you could have multiple phone numbers if they have different location types) I think it would solve the issue.

*EDIT* Upon closer inspection, the second "Other" number appears to duplicate the "Mobile" number. In the contact record, try deleting the duplicate number with the "Other" location type.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in theory they could experience similar duplicate results for contacts that have multiple emails and addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess - you have duplicate contacts.

I would check out the user guide - https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/online-event-registration/#contact-matching-and-duplicate-management

Go through your contacts and merge duplicates. (Contacts>>>Find and Merge duplicate contacts) Maybe start with a couple to see if that is the source of your issue.  This could have happened due to many factors - but most likely because you have a form or created an import and did not select any duplicate matching rules.